# Apple Maps business data - what sources and refresh rate?

Tags: local-seo, map, apple

I need to update/manage business data for 600+ locations in Apple Maps. I've read from various sources that Yelp appears to be the primary source of Apple Maps' data.

How frequently does Apple refresh the data? Are there any other means of controlling Apple Maps' business data that I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple Maps sources its business data from a large number of authoritative sources including Yelp and various yellow page business listings from around the world. The easiest way for you to manage your own business data though is to use Apple's MapConnect service designed specifically for managing your business data on Apple Maps, which can be found at https://mapsconnect.apple.com/.

Comment: Maps Connect works only for small businesses (max. 20 locations). Nevertheless, nice to finally get a helpful response on a 3 year old question! Thanks.

Comment: Well the only way to bulk upload more than 20 locations is of you are uploading 10'000 or more locations. As you have less than that you can look at using one of the information suppliers Apple Maps use which are...

DAC Group, Das Örtliche, Mobilosoft, Location3 Media, Marquette Group, NavAds, Neustar/Localeze, PagesJaunes (France), Placeable, PositionTech/allLocal, SIM Partners, SinglePlatform, uberall, UBL, YellowPages/PagesJaunes (Canada), Yellow Pages Turkey, Yelp, Yext and Yodle.

These companies upload large bulk data sets for their clients to Apple Maps.

Comment: @GDav - As a further to my last I have just checked with the MapsConnect team and have received an email back from them stating...

Maps Connect is the “tool" to manage business listings. You can do that even for 600+ locations. Unfortunately, at this moment in time, a bullk upload is not possible.

If you wish to discuss with them directly you can contact them at mapsconnect-business@apple.com.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the effort. I should stress my own need for this has long since passed - as I say, 3 year old question - but hopefully all this will be helpful to others.